# Как на ovh поменять главный ipv4 на один из failover адресов?

Tags: linux, debian, route

У меня ovh хост game1, система debian 9, на нем есть основной адрес и 10 адресов failover.
Я хочу сменить главный адрес на один из failover адресов.
Мне это необходимо, чтобы исходящие соединения не использовали главный адрес.

Допустим главный адрес это `43.144.13.127`, а failover - `32.114.67.212`

Текущий конфиг `/etc/systemd/network/50-default.network` у меня такой:

```
# This file sets the IP configuration of the primary (public) network device.
# You can also see this as "OSI Layer 3" config.
# It was created by the OVH installer, please be careful with modifications.
# Documentation: man systemd.network or https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

[Match]
MACAddress=s8:a1:22:5b:43:32

[Network]
Description=network interface on public network, with default route
DHCP=no
Address=43.144.13.127/24
Gateway=43.144.13.254
IPv6AcceptRA=no
NTP=ntp.ovh.net
DNS=127.0.0.1
DNS=213.186.33.99
DNS=1032:23d2:3:163::1
Gateway=1032:23d2:0222:42ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[Address]
Address=1032:23d2:0222:427f::/64

[Route]
Destination=1032:23d2:0222:42ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Scope=link

[Address]
Address=32.114.67.212/32
Label=failover

# ... и остальные failover адреса
```

Как сделать так, чтобы адрес `32.114.67.212` стал главным? То есть использовался для исходящих соединений?

Моя логика заключается в том, что раз я могу сделать исходящий запрос, вручную указав интерфейс, например так:

```
root@host:~# curl --interface failover ifconfig.me
32.114.67.212
```

Тогда должен быть способ указать этот интерфейс по умолчанию, но как?

Comment: посмотреть бы какие `ip a` и `ip r` такая конфигурация даёт... возможно, будет достаточно просто изменить маршрут по умолчанию: `ip r  change default via 32.114.67.212`... но как оно с networkd будет взаимодействовать я утверждать не решусь — какие-то больно странные адреса...

Comment: хех, адреса для вопроса я сделал рандомными, они не настоящие. окей попробую сделать, как вы предложили

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо, у меня получилось, правда команду пришлось немного поменять и ее окончательный вид `/bin/ip r change default via 43.144.13.254 dev enp1s0f0 proto static src 32.114.67.212`. Только вот как сделать так, чтобы после ребута хоста это правило сохраняло? По сути мне пришлось в `ip r` правилу добавить только в конец `src 32.114.67.212`, но я не знаю, как это прописать в `50-default.network`, я пробовал параметры `Source` и `PreferredSource`, они оба не работают. Так же я пытался команду выполнять через @reboot в cron, это тоже не работает, cron срабатывает первее, чем network.

Comment: как именно `PreferredSource` пробовал? по описанию похоже именно оно должно быть... если не сработает, то в классических debian'ах скрипт после подъёма интерфейса можно было запустить с помощью `post-up`, а в system.d похоже полноценный unit писать как-то [так](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started)

Comment: `PreferredSource` добавлял в секцию `[Route]`, перезапускал network, ребутил, в обоих случаях не генерировало `ip r` правильно, не было `src 32.114.67.212`. По поводу сервиса systemd я уже пробовал, правда я поменял `systemd-network.service`, добавив в него команду в `ExecStartPost`, это тоже не работает, команда точно выполняется я смотрел в syslog. Возможно, systemd-network лишь запускает процесс перезагрузки сети, но не ждет до конца и post команда запускается рано. `post-up` не пробовал, спасибо за совет, попробую, но смогу только ночью следующей.

Comment: `Gateway` из `[Network]` не забывал в тот же `[Route]` перенести? по поводу неработающего `ExecStartPost` — посмотри на права, от какого пользователя он там запускается... `post-up`'а как такового уже нет — он был во времена SysV'шного `init`'а, но если `ExecStartPost` не сработал из-за прав, то отдельный unit для скрипта может помочь...

Comment: `Gateway` не переносил в `[Route]`, а надо? По поводу `ExecStartPost` внутри systemctl конфига сервиса нет настройки юзера, вот собственно он https://paste.ee/p/afmCh, но тем не менее процесс сервиса работает от имени юзера `systemd-network`. Когда я тестил, то моя команда из `ExecStartPost` выполнялась успешно с exit code 0, я это видел, когда писал `systemctl status systemd-network`

Comment: почти наверняка надо... `Gateway` вроде как обязательный параметр для `[Route]` — о его отсутствии в секции должна была быть ошибка в логах... про `ExecStartPost` не буду утверждать ничего — я с systemd не так хорошо знаком... возможно оно просто действительно раньше выполняется, чем поднимается сеть...

Comment: `Gateway` в `[Route]` изначально не было с установкой системы, у меня стандартный образ debiab 9 от ovh. весь конфиг я в вопросе указал. в самом вверху конфига есть ссылка на доки https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html, там написано по поводу `Gateway` в `[Network]`. Но я все равно попробую это сделать ночью

Comment: и на всякий случай, нужно сделать отдельную секцию `[Route]`, а не добавлять в ту, в которой у тебя уже ipv6 адрес прописан...

Comment: @Fat-Zer у меня получилось, спасибо вам, вы очень помогли. вы были правы на счет отдельной секции `[Route]` и параметра `Gateway`. Окончательное решение я описал в своем ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью команды `ip r` это сделать можно так:

```
/bin/ip r change default via 43.144.13.254 dev enp1s0f0 proto static src 32.114.67.212
```

Но это правило не сохранится после ребута хоста. Чтобы оно сохранилось, нужно изменить конфигурацию `/etc/systemd/network/50-default.network` вот так:

```
# This file sets the IP configuration of the primary (public) network device.
# You can also see this as "OSI Layer 3" config.
# It was created by the OVH installer, please be careful with modifications.
# Documentation: man systemd.network or https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

[Match]
MACAddress=s8:a1:22:5b:43:32

[Network]
Description=network interface on public network, with default route
DHCP=no
Address=43.144.13.127/24
Gateway=43.144.13.254
IPv6AcceptRA=no
NTP=ntp.ovh.net
DNS=127.0.0.1
DNS=213.186.33.99
DNS=1032:23d2:3:163::1
Gateway=1032:23d2:0222:42ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[Address]
Address=1032:23d2:0222:427f::/64

[Route]
Destination=1032:23d2:0222:42ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Scope=link

[Route]
Gateway=43.144.13.254
PreferredSource=51.195.48.249

[Address]
Address=32.114.67.212/32
Label=failover

# ... и остальные failover адреса
```

Изменения:

- Была добавлена новая секция `[Route]`, в которой добавлено два параметра:

  - `PreferredSource` - в этом параметре указан адрес, который мы хотим сделать
    адресом для исходящих соединений (в моем случае `32.114.67.212`).
  - `Gateway` - значение этого параметра берем из одноименного параметра из секции `[Network]`.

После изменения конфига, нужно перезагрузить сеть командой:

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Готово.